# Why do I get apache2 welcome page while apache2 is not running?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, services, nginx

I want to use nginx on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. So I started by stopping and removing apache2 with:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2
```

apache2 seems to be successfully removed:

```
$ sudo service apache2 status
apache2: unrecognized service
```

So I installed nginx and I run it successfully:

```
$ sudo service nginx status
nginx start/running, process 8593
```

But when I visit the server in the browser (with the naked IP-address) it still gives me the apache2 welcome page ("It works!", but why?!?). I refreshed, tried different browsers and incognito-views, but to no avail.

I'm 100% sure the ip-address matches (I copy-pasted it from my ssh login command).

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Page cached in browser?

Comment: Maybe the `service apache2 stop` command failed and even if you uninstalled it, the running process remained. You can verify it with `netstat -atpn | grep 80`, check the PID and match it with `ps aux | grep PID`

Comment: You did verify the actual file on disk, right?

Comment: @nKn - I was just thinking the same, so I rebooted, but I still get the apache page. The weird thing was that the apache welcome page remained up while I was rebooting. Could it be that the server is behind some kind of proxy which runs an apache server?

Comment: @kramer65 - You do understand once you are sent the page, you browser keeps that in a cache, so unless the content changes even with the server offline in most cases your browser would continue to display the cache page.

Comment: @DanielB - Which file are you talking about?

Comment: @kramer65 The demo page. It’s not something magical but rather a regular file that’s part of the software package. It may or may not have remained when uninstalling Apache.

Comment: @DanielB - That was it, thank you! I feel pretty stupid about this. I "assumed" that uninstalling apache would also remove the apache welcome page, but it clearly doesn't. Nginx was just serving the apache welcome page. If you post your tip as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “It works” page is not built into Apache itself, but shipped with it. Your earlier installation of the Apache package probably left that file behind in the HTTP server directory (`/srv/http`, `/var/www/` or whatever). The nginx package is configured to not replace existing files in that directory. They could be user-made, after all.

So that means the actual on-disk file is still the Apache one.